# How to have responsive facebook post, and get auto height

Tags: responsive

I want to have responsive facebook post on my website.

The problem is, if I do iframe width 100%; the height is not well calculated.

Example :

```
<div>
debut
</div>
<iframe src="https://www.facebook.com/plugins/post.php?href=https%3A%2F%2Fwww.facebook.com%2FJLMelenchon%2Fposts%2F10157456109273750&amp" width="100%" height="auto" style="border:none;overflow:hidden" scrolling="no" frameborder="0" allowTransparency="true" allow="encrypted-media"></iframe>
<div>text</div>

 html, body, iframe { width: 100%; }
```

http://jsfiddle.net/amineharoun/ut8975pb/

[see screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/VHq1Q.png)

Each facebook post has a different height, I want to make width : 100%; adaptive to different screen width:

[image]

[image]

[image]

Comment: If I understood your post. Add css min-height and max-height and also overflowy: scroll to your IFrame

Comment: i cant do that, because each facebook post has a different height, I want to make width : 100%; adaptative to different screen width

Comment: So if you add width:100% then height not getting calculated very well right

Comment: Use width: 100vw and height:100vh

Comment: when I do that, the iframe take full height, and not the only height that enougth

http://jsfiddle.net/amineharoun/ut8975pb/4/

Comment: Then use height:auto

Comment: when i do height auto, it doesnt set the right height, as you see in my screenshot
https://i.stack.imgur.com/VHq1Q.png

is there a way to get the height of the body with js ? the probleme is there is a security probleme that dont let me get the height

Comment: Then play with min-height with specific view height. With important tag. I.e min-height:35vh! important;

Comment: the probleme is if i set a specific height, it will not be responsive, remember that i want to have different screen widths

Comment: Min-height is not equal to heght. For different  screen width use media queries as @media screen (width: your width){your css}

Comment: the probleme is each post facebook has there height, it's a website that let admin add post facebook each day to my website, and the admin is not an informaticien, so i just want to let there post the facebook post,  and i want create a script that adjust height automaticaly

Comment: If post is too large then what to do. That's why use min-height: your minimum height in vh  and max-height,  and width for different screen size use media queries. Just Google for media queries

Comment: look at this fiddle : http://jsfiddle.net/amineharoun/ut8975pb/11/
 [1]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/VHq1Q.png
 [2]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/J98oS.png
 [3]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/wV7FI.png
 [4]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/kassT.png

Can you please help me to fixe that (editing the fiddle) ?

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/amineharoun/ut8975pb/14/

Comment: have you found any solution? @AmineHaroun